# Using S3 as a primary database for web applications

Tags: java, database, amazon-s3, caching

Apart from [Dyno](https://github.com/divroll/dyno) are there any efforts to use S3 (Amazon, Wasabi, or S3-Compatible) object storage as a primary database? For example, storing JSON data and other entities.

*S3 does not offer atomic transaction nor batch transactions*, thus, in order to prevent key duplication or key accidentally overridden by other instances of an application (for example) a distributed caching of keys is required afaik (e.g. using EHCache or something similar.) This is one of the main drawbacks I can see.

Similarly, if you need to have your application have an "all-or-nothing", again transactions, e.g. store two objects or none at all, this is not possible except (at least solving one part of the problem) to have a distributed locking mechanism, as such an instance of an application, can have an exclusive lock for a certain period of time for the keys to store while it is actually saving to S3.

**How do you implement such a mechanism to emulate transactions when using S3 as the primary database?**

Answer (score 1):

You might implement an [append-only database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Append-only) that is a log of transactions, but it won't be too efficient.

The problem with S3 is that it provides [read after write](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) consistency, but otherwise you can't really depend on things being consistent.